# REDCap API logging to retrieve records timestamps: how to re-format json response?

Tags: python, api, redcap

I have REDCap project with some instruments/forms that do not have date collection. So I would like to use REDCap API to export logging but format return is quite 'strange'.

It return a list of dict with 4 keys: timestamp, username, action and details.

I save api response in a json file and open file in my browser. Record number #84 correspond to instrument fin_de_ltude_anticov_j21 for patient number #001 that have been created (updated with respect to action mentioned) on 2021-09-11 11:23.

Detail is a string which is not really easy to manipulate.
For a given patient, I could iterate over api json response and search in details string if details contain substring 'fin_de_ltude_anticov_j21' and consider the timestamp's oldest records as being patient's fin_de_ltude_anticov_j21 instrument creation but there is probably a better approach?

[image]

Comment: I would seek help from your REDCap Administrators. Are you trying to backfill survey completion dates, or data entry form dates? If the former, recent versions added a smart variable [survey-date-completed:instrument] which retrieves the date from the survey database tables. You can put this into a @CALCDATE field and run DQ rule H to backfill for your entire dataset.

Comment: Yes I do but did not really know about RedCap API. Moreover, Redcap project's database is already built with datas collected. And timestamp was not planned. We did not use survey.